# Import SWF with an other SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a problem !
I have two SWF.
One with the game that we created and an other one with the MainMenu of the game.

I want to load the SWF of the game when I Click on play on the MainMenu.
I add this code on the first frame of the MainMenu :

```
btnJouer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,jouer);

function jouer(pEvt:MouseEvent){
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("testMouvement.swf"); 
    var loader:Loader = new Loader() 
    loader.load(request); 
    Security.allowDomain(loader.contentLoaderInfo.url);
    addChild(loader);
}
```

But when I click on play I hear the sound of my game but the game don't appear..

I have some error when I click on play but I don't understand ..
If I load the swf of the game without the mainmenu everything work fine..

The Error when I click on play :

```
*TypeError: Error #1009: Il est impossible d'accéder à la propriété ou à la méthode d'une référence d'objet nul.
    at cem::saut()[C:\Users\1124889\Desktop\Prog3.2\cem\saut.as:58]
    at hero()
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at cem::application()[C:\Users\1124889\Desktop\Prog3.2\cem\application.as:69]
TypeError: Error #1009: Il est impossible d'accéder à la propriété ou à la méthode d'une référence d'objet nul.
    at cem::saut2()[C:\Users\1124889\Desktop\Prog3.2\cem\saut2.as:52]
    at hero2()
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at cem::application()[C:\Users\1124889\Desktop\Prog3.2\cem\application.as:69]
TypeError: Error #1009: Il est impossible d'accéder à la propriété ou à la méthode d'une référence d'objet nul.
    at cem::application()[C:\Users\1124889\Desktop\Prog3.2\cem\application.as:70]*
```

Sorry for my english am french.
Thank you if someone can help me !

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'll just answer here.

If you want to load external SWF into your own SWF, you'll need to use `SWFLoader`

I've answered more thoroughly here: [Actionscript 3 - List error when loading another a swf in my swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304899/actionscript-3-list-error-when-loading-another-a-swf-in-my-swf/23361092#23361092)